# Proper way to run nameko service(s) inside a Django application?

Tags: django, integration, nameko

If I have a vanilla Django REST (DRF) application and I would like to integrate a nameko service (specifically an `event_handler` event listening service), what's the best way to achieve this?

I cannot simply `nameko run` a service if it's part of a Django application.

I'm considering running the nameko service via a custom Django management command, but would I lose some of nameko's features, say, scalability? Eg. nameko maintains a pool of 10 workers per `nameko run` (if I remember correctly).

Comment: I don't know much of nameko, but as far as I have seen from docs, I don't think you should make it a management command. As far as I understand(and I could be wrong), you should make it an standalone web service and communicate it from django via REST api

Answer (score 1):

This is how:

https://github.com/sivabudh/djanko/blob/master/services.py

See: django-nameko-standalone

Update: If you want to do microservices with Django, just use Celery. Works like a charm.